# He left her a widow

Tags: syntax, ambiguity, semantics

> He left her a widow.

I think this sentence is ambiguous.

The possible meanings are:

**1. He died and she became a widow.**

**2. He kept a widow in her care.**

Could you please analyze the sentences and say if I am right or wrong.?

When somebody listens to the sentence, will he understand the sentence both ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example, contained in a joke, of the type of alleged ambiguity you mentioned in your question: graffiti on wall of cubicle in UK public toilet: "my mother made me a homosexual". Underneath, someone else had written: "If I sent her the wool, would she make me one as well?"

Another example:

> My father made me an athlete.

An examination of the words might make a naive person think that there are two meanings:

1. My father's actions in my childhood resulted in me becoming an athlete
2. My father constructed, manufactured or created an athlete as a gift for me.

Native speakers will see no ambiguity, and see meaning (1), because of "common sense" (the things that 'everybody knows'), which tells them that a person cannot be be manufactured as in meaning (2). So it is that native speakers will perceive your expression with the first meaning you gave, "he died and she became a widow".

Answer (score 4):

Both meanings are possible, but the first (that he died and his wife became a widow) will be overwhelmingly assumed unless there is clear context to select the other. And if the other meaning were really the one intended, most writers would probably find a different way to phrase it to avoid the much more common interpretation.